# How can I save enumeration value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, strapi

How can I save enumeration value in TypeScript?

For example:

```
createArticle(name: string, clr: ??enumeration??) {
    return axios.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/cards`, {
        card: `${name}`,
        color: ??clr?? 
    },
    ...
}
```

PS: [Content Type Setting in Strapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH1AC.png)

Comment: What do you *mean*?

Comment: What's up with `??enumeration??`, is that your way of saying you expect enum type here, maybe `keyof` ?

Comment: Hello, I have a Strapi BackEnd and am currently trying to write a front end in Angular. Unfortunately, I do not know how to send an enumeration value in TS to my Strapi BackEnd.

Comment: Yes, keyof! 
Can I just write "keyof", I will test it.

Comment: @BenjaminReeves Google, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I had spaces in the setting.
instead of "red, white, blue, green" I should write "red,white,blue,green".

Thanks to you all!